# Javers and Transactions

Tags: spring-boot, javers

I have small spring application
Some repository with - **@JaversSpringDataAuditable**

All work fine
https://javers.org/documentation/spring-integration/

```
From now, all objects passed to save() and delete() methods will be automatically audited by JaVers — AWESOME!
```

Is it possible to combine calls to
*repository.delete* and *repository.save* into one audit log entry?

```
@Transactional
public void test(){
   var entity=
...
   testRepository.delete(entity);
...
   testRepository.save(entity);
}
```

Now every call to delete or save creates an entry in the audit log

Answer (score 1):

You mean combine these two things in one javers' commit? For now there is no such option.